# How to add a scrollpane in the frame window

Tags: java, arrays, jframe, window, jscrollpane

I want to add a scrollpane in the frame window or comboPanel.

Below code, the `guiFrame.add(scrollpane)` is not working, why it is not working?

How can I add the scrollpane to comboPanel or the guiFrame?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ExtraComboBox {
    private int maxFields = 4; // The max number of fields allowed in the dialog
    JComboBox fruits[] = new JComboBox[maxFields];
    JPanel comboPanel;
    JFrame guiFrame;
    String[] valOptions3 = { "&" };
    String[] valOptions2 = { "|->", "|=>" };
    String[] valOptions1 = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
    String[] valOptions0 = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
    String[] fruitOptions1 = { "", "Delay1", "Delay2", "Delay3" };
    JButton addField;
    int count1 = 0;

    JLabel dudel[] = new JLabel[maxFields];
    JComboBox dude2[] = new JComboBox[maxFields];
    String[] valOptions = { "Unknown", "0", "1" };
    String[] s = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i" };
    private JLabel comboLbl;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ExtraComboBox();
    }

    public ExtraComboBox() {
        guiFrame = new JFrame();

        // make sure the program exits when the frame closes
        guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        guiFrame.setTitle("ComboBox GUI");
        guiFrame.setSize(350, 350);

        // The first JPanel contains a JLabel and JCombobox
        comboPanel = new JPanel();

        addField = new JButton("Add Field");
        addField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                if (event.getSource().equals(addField)) {
                    if (count1 < maxFields) {
                        comboLbl = new JLabel("Select a relation:");
                        fruits[count1] = new JComboBox<String>(fruitOptions1);
                        MyItemListener2 actionListener2 = new MyItemListener2(count1);
                        fruits[count1].addItemListener(actionListener2);
                        // System.out.println("HI: " + fruits[count1].getParent());
                        dude2[count1] = new JComboBox<String>();
                        System.out.println("ADD FIELDS: " + count1);
                        comboPanel.add(comboLbl);
                        comboPanel.add(fruits[count1]);
                        comboPanel.add(dude2[count1]);
                        guiFrame.validate();
                        guiFrame.repaint();
                        count1++;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("You reached the maximum of 4 fields.");
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        comboPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(comboPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        comboPanel.add(addField);
        // The JFrame uses the BorderLayout layout manager.
        // Put the two JPanels and JButton in different areas.
        guiFrame.add(comboPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        // make sure the JFrame is visible
        guiFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class MyItemListener2 implements ItemListener {
        private int index;

        public MyItemListener2(int pIndex) {
            super();
            index = pIndex;
        }

        // This method is called only if a new item has been selected.
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {

            if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                // Item was just selected
                System.out.println("COUNTER: " + index);
                System.out.println(evt.getItem());

                dude2[index].removeAllItems();
                switch ((String) evt.getItem()) {
                case "Delay1":
                    for (int i = 0; i < valOptions1.length; i++) {
                        dude2[index].addItem(valOptions1[i]); // dude1 = new JComboBox(valOptions1);
                        System.out.println(valOptions1[i]);
                    }
                    break;
                case "Delay2": 
                    for (int j = 0; j < valOptions2.length; j++) {
                        System.out.println(valOptions2[j]);
                        dude2[index].addItem(valOptions2[j]); // dude1 = new JComboBox(valOptions1);
                    }
                    break;
                case "Delay3":
                    for (int j = 0; j < valOptions3.length; j++) {
                        System.out.println(valOptions3[j]);
                        dude2[index].addItem(valOptions3[j]); // dude1 = new JComboBox(valOptions1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What scrollpane? What do you mean "it doesn't work"? What do you expect it to do, and what does it do instead? Where do you pack the frame?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I add the scrollpane to comboPanel or the guiFrame?

You add the comboPanel to the `JViewport` of the `JScrollPane` and then you add the scroll pane to the JFrame.

```
//guiFrame.add(comboPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( comboPanel );
guiFrame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

It is better to add the scrollpane to the CENTER, then it will get all the space available to the frame.